# Yii2 ActiveFormAsset dependencies

Tags: yii2

I'm foregoing Yii2's bundled jQuery and Bootstrap assets in exchange for ones I've bundled myself using `npm`/`browserify` So step one was to remove jQuery and Bootstrap from `yii\web\YiiAsset` via the config:

```
'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'css' => [],
                ],

            ],
        ],
...
]
```

I want to put this in the footer, obviously, but it needs to load before any other assets so that jQuery is available to them.

Here's my AssetBundle:

```
class AppAssets extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $depends = [
        'app\assets\CustomAssets',
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    ];
}
```

With my CustomAssets bundle (that contains my own JS and CSS) declared first in `depends`, I think this *would* work, but I also have an ActiveForm on the page, and this registers [its own asset bundle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeformasset.html), which is dependent on the various Yii assets. Here's where I embed that form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>
            ...
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Is there a way I can override the `depends` on `ActiveFormAsset` so that it also depends on my scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Since asset bundle dependencies are transitive, it occurred to me that in the same way I'm overriding the config for the `Jquery` and `Bootstrap` bundles, I can override the config for `yii\web\YiiAsset` like so:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            ...
            'yii\web\YiiAsset' => [
                'depends' => [
                    'app\assets\CustomAssets',
                ],
             ],
        ],
    ],
    ...
]
```

So when `ActiveFormAsset` tries to load `yii\web\YiiAsset`, it processes the dependency on my own scripts/styles, and also covers any other assets that get loaded and might depend on `yii\web\YiiAsset`.

Answer (score 0):

what i did was replacing shipped assets, instead of killing them:

```
    'bundles'            => [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'       => ['class' => 'common\assets\BootstrapAsset',],
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => ['class' => 'common\assets\BootstrapPluginAsset',],
    ],
```